# @login_required decorator doesnot work while hitting the back button on browser

Tags: python, django, python-decorators, login-required

This is my first time using decorator for django. I am able to restirct the unauthenticated users from accessing certain views. I am only able to view the page by loggin in which is perfect but when i hit the back button after loggin out from the restricted page, it just goes back to restricted page.

Heres my view:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render_to_response('/blog/login.html')

category = Category.objects.all()
return render_to_response('dashboard.html',{'category':category})
```

Settings.py:

```
#URL for @login_required decorator to use
LOGIN_URL = '/blog/login/'

#Redirect Authenticated USers
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/blog/dashboard/'
```

Heres my logout View:

```
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return render_to_response('login.html')
```

Comment: you should redirect after a logout.

Comment: I did this: `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')` but didnt helped! Did you mean this?? @thebjorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loggout view should not be a real view, just a URL route that will loggout and redirect the user to another view, you can also force the browser to not cache using the cache_control decorator.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I did that in my login view, logout view and dashboard view. That didnt helped.

Comment: The redirection itself should prevent the user from seeing the page again, also make sure using firebug that the sent headrs have these set: `patch_cache_control(response, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)`